# How to swap/shuffle values within a column in R?

Tags: r, swap, shuffle

I want to anonymize data using cell swapping. Therefore I want to conditionally swap values within a column.

My data looks like:

```
Sex     Age    Houeshold_size
 0       95          2
 0       95          3
 1       90          1
 1       90          5
 1       45          1
 1       45          1
 1       34          1
 1       34          1
 1       34          1
 1       34          1
```

I want to give swap values so everyone above a certain age has a household size of 1. In this case 90 or older. So my outcome has to look like:

```
Sex     Age    Houeshold_size
 0       95          1
 0       95          1
 1       90          1
 1       90          1
 1       45          1
 1       45          1
 1       34          2
 1       34          3
 1       34          5
 1       34          1
```

It is more that I want to know how to conditionally swap data instead of solving this example, since its just a fraction of my data.

Thanks for helping me out, cheers.

Comment: I think you  are looking for `ifelse`, for example `df$Houeshold_size <- ifelse(df$Age >= 90, 1, df$Houeshold_size)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following :

```
#Get the index where Age is 90 or higher
inds <- which(df$Age >= 90)
#replace `Houeshold_size` where age is less than 90 with that of inds
df$Houeshold_size[sample(which(df$Age < 90), length(inds))] <- df$Houeshold_size[inds]
#Change household size of inds to 1
df$Houeshold_size[inds] <- 1


#   Sex Age Houeshold_size
#1    0  95              1
#2    0  95              1
#3    1  90              1
#4    1  90              1
#5    1  45              1
#6    1  45              3
#7    1  34              2
#8    1  34              1
#9    1  34              1
#10   1  34              5
```